# jacaco unit test coverage reports path and file name(as jacaco.exec)

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

I am running following maven command on jenkins

clean org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent install

The jacaco exec file created as shown below.
target/coverage-reports/jacoco-int-test.exec

I would like to generate this file under following path, since all other Project use same conventions.
target/jacoco.exec

I could not figureout why it is generated in this way and how to modify it as "target/jacoco.exec"

I will use this report in sonarqube analysis.

I would appriciate your helps, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

As per documentation of [prepare-agent - **destFile** parameter controls location of output file](http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/prepare-agent-mojo.html#destFile), whose default is `${project.build.directory}/jacoco.exec` which is exactly `target/jacoco.exe`. So check your POMs to find where it is modified to be `target/coverage-reports/jacoco-int-test.exec`.